# Pandas track status changes rows

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe that looks like,

| Patientid | status_may | status_june |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | admitted | discharged |
| 5678 | admitted | admitted |
| 9443 | admitted | deceased |

and so on. If I want to count how many went from admitted-discharged, admitted-admitted, admitted - decesead and a percentage of those that moved. Is there a way to do that in pandas.

so return something like

| Change | Count | proportion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| adm-disch | 5 | 50% |
| adm-adm | 3 | 30% |
| adm-dec | 2 | 20% |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd 
d = {'Patientid': [1234, 5678,9443,1233],
     'status_may': ['admitted', 'admitted','admitted','admitted'],
    'status_june' : ['discharged','admitted','deceased','discharged']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['change']=df['status_may']+'-'+df['status_june']
df=df[['change','status_may']].groupby(by='change').count().reset_index().rename(columns={'status_may':'Count'})
df['proportion']=(df['Count']/df['Count'].sum())*100
df
```

Output :

[image]